# Install latest Osmosis version on Ubuntu

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, osmosis, ubuntugis

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to know the easiest way to install the latest (stable) version of Osmosis, which is 0.44.

I ran

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install osmosis
osmosis -v
```

That last command returns many lines, but the second is

```
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.40.1
```

0.40 seems to have too many problems with 64-bit integers. So I want to download the latest stable, but I don't know where Osmosis is currently installed to and thus where I should copy the downloaded files to.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Downloading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding the location of your current executable can be done with `which` and `ls -l` can show you where the symlink points:

```
which osmosis | xargs ls -l
```

If you know the location just follow the [Install instructions for pre-built binaries](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Installation#Installing_pre-built_Osmosis):

```
wget http://bretth.dev.openstreetmap.org/osmosis-build/osmosis-latest.tgz
mkdir osmosis-new
mv osmosis-latest.tgz osmosis-new
cd osmosis-new
tar xvfz osmosis-latest.tgz
rm osmosis-latest.tgz
chmod a+x bin/osmosis
cd .. 
mv osmosis-new/* /your/osmosis/install/location/
```

Comment: Ahh, the `which` command, I need to remember that more.

It returned `/usr/bin/osmosis` which was a file rather than a directory. I tried several things before deciding I was best to delete my attempts and start the installation from scratch (into any folder in my home directory that I won't delete). The `readme.txt` contains instructions to make a symbolic link in your user bin (probably what that file was!) and now I've done that I can return to using the `osmosis` command without caring where it is.

Comment: Somewhere on my computer I guess I have an old copy of osmosis, I should do a file search for that if I want to clean it up.

If you update your answer to mention `which` may return a symbolic link, then I will happily mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Gregory valid remark. I included the listing of symlinks and where they point to